# Exporting a Powershell object containing multiple sets to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have a Powershell object which is the result of DSInternals Test-PasswordQuality cmdlet that I'd like to use as a Power BI dataset; it's a bunch of sets of user accounts, ex.

```
PS C:\> $result | get-member


   TypeName: DSInternals.PowerShell.PasswordQualityTestResult

Name                       MemberType Definition
----                       ---------- ----------
Equals                     Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode                Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType                    Method     type GetType()
ToString                   Method     string ToString()
AESKeysMissing             Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] AESKeysMissing {get;set;}
ClearTextPassword          Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] ClearTextPassword {get;set;}
DefaultComputerPassword    Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] DefaultComputerPassword {get;set;}
DelegatableAdmins          Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] DelegatableAdmins {get;set;}
DESEncryptionOnly          Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] DESEncryptionOnly {get;set;}
DuplicatePasswordGroups    Property   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string]] DuplicatePasswordGroup… 
EmptyPassword              Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] EmptyPassword {get;set;}
Kerberoastable             Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] Kerberoastable {get;set;}
LMHash                     Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] LMHash {get;set;}
PasswordNeverExpires       Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] PasswordNeverExpires {get;set;}
PasswordNotRequired        Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] PasswordNotRequired {get;set;}
PreAuthNotRequired         Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] PreAuthNotRequired {get;set;}
SmartCardUsersWithPassword Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] SmartCardUsersWithPassword {get;set;}
WeakPassword               Property   System.Collections.Generic.ISet[string] WeakPassword {get;set;}
```

```
PS C:\> $result | select LMHash


LMHash
------
{a_user, another_user, yet_another_user…}
```

I'd like to export this to one csv where each array is its own column. If I simply do

```
$result | export-csv .\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I do get a separate column for each set, but then just the the Set object type under each, ex.

[image: first two columns]

How can I get a list of users, with each user in it's own cell, like this?

[image: desired first two columns]

**UPDATE**

As an example, one of the elements of `$result.PSObject.Properties` is:

```
MemberType      : Property
Value           : {user, another_user, another_user…}
IsSettable      : True
IsGettable      : True
TypeNameOfValue : System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                  PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
Name            : LMHash
IsInstance      : True
```

So I think I need to iterate through the `$result.PSObject.Properties` for the column names and then also iterate through essentially `$(result.PSObject.Properties).Value` to get the users into separate cells in the csv. But doing them via index, i.e. `$(result.PSObject.Properties).Value[1]` results in the property types in the csv instead of the actual values. I tried nested foreach loops but still couldn't quite crack it.

Comment: What output does the code from the previous answer produce?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/l2vCjrP)

Answer (score 0):

Given the scenario, you can use a loop (*in this case I will use a `for` loop to demonstrate this*) to iterate through the listings using a `PSCustomObject`:

```
$maxCount = [math]::Max($result.LMHash.Count,$result.ClearTextPassword.Count)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxCount; $i++)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        LMHash = $result.LMHash[$i]
        ClearTextPassword = $result.ClearTextPassword[$i]
    } #| Export-Csv -Path ".\result.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

`$maxCount` will be the max number of iterations the `for` loop should iterate to; given those two properties of *LMHash*, and *ClearTextPassword*.

Comment: This actually has the same result in the csv as I posted above, the Column Headers with SortedSet object types. The output pre-csv looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/LaRCr0E) (usernames redacted)

Comment: can you try it with the edit?

Comment: Same result in the CSV. The command output looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/l2vCjrP)

Comment: That don't make sense to me since there are only 2 properties in the `pscustomobject` i've posted above, and there are 3 that you're showing in your pic. Please post how you're using the code.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. If you look at the list of objects I posted, there are many more than just the LMHash and ClearTextPassword properties; I used the same screenshot to answer your comment as I did Santiago's because the result (cells with the named Set properties) was the same, though I was using all properties on his. The result of your edited code as written is [this](https://imgur.com/lnLXt94)